# Turning on information management policy causes security exception

Tags: 2010, code-access-security

I have some code:

```
            SPFieldMultiChoice category = (SPFieldMultiChoice)contentType.Fields["Category"];
```

Where contentType is a `SPContentType` instance.

This works fine as part of some code that runs in `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges()`. Well, that is until I configure an information management policy on the content type. Now it throws a security exception... "That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers. mscorlib"

If I turn the retention policy off everything is fine again... What am I doing wrong? Do I have to set my solution up as fully trusted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not the first to ask this question ;) , I hope this article answeres your question :) sounds like you have run into the same issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692/information-management-policy-in-sharepoint

hope it helps :)